# using ubuntu-one on other linux distros?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm running different OS on my computers windows ubuntu and also Opensuse 12.3.
I'm a user of ubuntu-one and I use it without any problem on windows and ubuntu but I cant find any rpm or source code to install or compile it on opensuse.

Can I use ubuntu-one on other linux distros like opensuse? If so How?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, there are tarball releases of all the client software, and anyone is free to package it on their favorite Linux distro. There are some users who are already using it on Fedora, Arch, and Gentoo - [Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/375349).

- [Fedora](http://www.maxiberta.com.ar/blog/ubuntuone-packages-fedora)
- [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=ubuntuone)

OpenSuse? [Nope](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse/2009-07/msg00971.html)... but that is not Ubuntu's fault ;)

If you want total cross platform use Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to install but;

```
# sudo apt-get install alien
# sudo alien -r ubuntuone-<whatever>.deb
```

> "ubuntuone-.rpm generated"

**might** help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on opensuse 12.3 or other opensuse distros

http://software.opensuse.org/package/ubuntuone-client